# what to return when terminating the process with process.exit(1);

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I would like to replace my `throw new Error('Unknown command.')` with a log statement and `process.exit(1);`. Given this example code

```
private getCommandByName = (name: string): ICommand => {
    try {
        // try to fetch a value from a map
        return <ICommand> this.commands.get(name);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Unknown command.');
        process.exit(1);
    }
}
```

I get this error

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not
>   include 'undefined'.

To fix it I would have to throw an exception. What do I have to return when I want to terminate the process?

Comment: `ICommand | never`

Comment: sorry, this doesn't work. I still get the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do:

```
return process.exit(1);
```

Since `exit` method returns `never` type compiler will not complain.

[Learn more](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/never.html) about `never` type

Comment: sorry, didn't know I had to use a return for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type cast:

```js
private getCommandByName = (name: string): ICommand => {
    try {
        // try to fetch a value from a map
        return <ICommand> this.commands.get(name);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Unknown command.');
        process.exit(1);
        return null as unknown as ICommand;
    }
}
```